# mongorestore syntax error

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have lots of bson files in the following path:

```
c:/mongodb/bin/dump/Sid
```

If I run the command:

```
> mongorestore --db Sid --drop dump/Sid
```

I get the following error:

```
Mon Mar 26 14:36:36 SyntaxError: missing ; before statement (shell):1
```

What is the problem with my command?

Comment: Why do you add `--drop dump/Sid`?

Comment: @Sergio came accross that command in a post. how can I restore that folder?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From your input, it appears as though you are attempting to run mongorestore from inside the JS shell.

Mongorestore is a standalone application, and is run directly from the terminal.

The following will not work:

```
c:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2012-03-20\bin>mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version: 2.1.1-pre-
connecting to: test
> mongorestore --db test --drop \dump\test
Mon Mar 26 11:29:13 SyntaxError: missing ; before statement (shell):1
>
```

If you run mongorestore directly from the terminal you should be successful:

```
c:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2012-03-20\bin>mongorestore --db test --drop \dump\test
connected to: 127.0.0.1
... (truncated for brevity) ...

c:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2012-03-20\bin>
```

The documentation on Mongodump / mongorestore may be found in the "Import Export Tools" documentation: 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools

Comment: this was extremely helpful for a n00b like me.  I could not figure out what was going on as it's not clear in the docs that `mongorestore` should be run from the terminal, not from the mongo shell.

Answer (score 3):

**mongorestore is not a command** , it an executable in the bin directory of MongoDB.
Below is the quote from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/

> The mongorestore program writes data from a binary database dump
>   created by mongodump to a MongoDB instance. mongorestore can create a
>   new database or add data to an existing database.

If you already have a mongod instance running 
where you already specified the dbpath as

```
mongod  --dbpath "..\mongodb\data"
```

you can directly run the mongorestore command .

```
mongorestore ..\data\dump
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore the outside database then copy that database in

```
<pre>C:\database drive(Create a folder database and copy your database) ,then follow the steps
1)c:\> cd database
2)c:\database>dir
3)c:\database>"\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\mongorestore.exe"

now open robomongo and check it will contain the restored dbs.. or check on command prompt show dbs</pre>
```